# How do I update a Core Data entity from a child view?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a `Thing` Core Data entity with a `name` field. When I display a `[Thing]` in a `List`, I want to be able to edit the `name` inside the child views. Here's the code that does achieve this, but it feels like poor architecture. A `ThingView` should really be passed `thing`, not the `thing.name`!

Instead, I really want to pass the `Thing` to `ThingView`, but if I just did that, then updating `thing.name` would not cause the view to update because `Thing` is a reference type. Any thoughts on clean design here?

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var observableAllData: ObservableAllData
  var body: some View {
      NavigationView{List(observableAllData.allData.things.indices) { index in
        NavigationLink(destination:ThingView(
          thingName: $observableAllData.allData.things[index].name)) { 
            Text(observableAllData.allData.things[index].name)}
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ThingView: View {
  @Binding var thingName: String
  func updateThing() {
    thingName = "NEW"
  }
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Text(thingName)
      Button(action: updateThing) { Text("Update it!")}
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: Clarification that I want both the `ThingView` and the `ContentView`
to update when clicking on "Update it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass inside `ThingView` complete `Thing` object and use it there instead of its property. Such you will be able update it and save.

So

```
struct ThingView: View {
  @ObservedObject var thing: Thing

  func updateThing() {
    thing.name = "NEW"
    try? thing.managedObjectContext?.save()
  }
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Text(thing.name)
      Button(action: updateThing) { Text("Update it!")}
    }
  }
}
```

and in link

```
NavigationLink(destination:ThingView(
  thing: observableAllData.allData.things[index])) {
```

**Update:** pattern is the same everything dependent on CoreData entity put into separated view and make it observed that entity.

In your extended question / what's not very polite ;) / put row into separated view

```
struct ThingRowView: View {
  @ObservedObject var thing: Thing
   var body: some View {
      NavigationLink(destination:ThingView(thing: thing) { 
            Text(thing.name)}
      }
   }
}
```

and call it

```
  NavigationView{List(observableAllData.allData.things.indices) { index in
     ThingRowView(thing: observableAllData.allData.things[index])
  }
```

Comment: When I try this, I get `Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Thing>' to expected argument type 'Thing'`

Comment: See updated, I forgot to remove $ from copied code from question.

Comment: Thanks! Now it runs: Clicking "Updating it" *does* now update the `ThingView`, *but it does not update the Parent View* (the `List`). Clarified the question accordingly that I want both views to update.

Comment: Thank you, it works beautifully. And apologies for the edit, it wasn't meant as an extension, because I'm not familiar enough with SwiftUI that this requires a design change. Really appreciated.